# Errors with Comparator implementation in Java

Tags: java, comparator

This is my implemention of a comparator.

```
class Checker implements Comparator<Player> {
    private static final Comparator<Player> asc = Comparator
        .comparingInt(Player::score).thenComparing(Player::name);
    private static final Comparator<Player> desc = asc.reversed();

    private final boolean descending;

    public int compare(Player player1, Player player2) {
        Comparator<Player> sorter = descending ? desc : asc;
        return sorter.compare(player1, player2);
    }
}
```

This is my Player object.

```
class Player
{
    String name;
    int score;
}
```

This is how the Comparator gets called. The calling code is provided and I cannot modify it.

```
Checker check = new Checker();
Arrays.sort(Player,check.desc);
```

This is the compilation I'm getting. The main class is name Solution. Line 6 is the line of code where Player::score gets called first.

```
 Solution.java:6: error: ')' expected
        .comparingInt(Player::score).thenComparing(Player::name);
                            ^
Solution.java:6: error: illegal start of type
        .comparingInt(Player::score).thenComparing(Player::name);
                             ^
Solution.java:6: error: ';' expected
        .comparingInt(Player::score).thenComparing(Player::name);
                                   ^
Solution.java:6: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
        .comparingInt(Player::score).thenComparing(Player::name);
                                     ^
Solution.java:6: error: <identifier> expected
        .comparingInt(Player::score).thenComparing(Player::name);
                                                         ^
Solution.java:6: error: ';' expected
        .comparingInt(Player::score).thenComparing(Player::name);
                                                          ^
Solution.java:6: error: <identifier> expected
        .comparingInt(Player::score).thenComparing(Player::name);
```

Comment: Down voter what's your argument, please?

Comment: OT hint: `desc = desc.reversed()`? ;-)

Comment: @flo you could edit that rather than just pointing out

Comment: FYI, the `::` scope resolution operator is in C++ but not Java (unless they slipped it in recently). Java uses dot (`.`) for [static] class members, object members, and packages.

Comment: @MikeHarris It seems that :: has been added. (java 8 maybe?) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: @Josejulio Thanks! I did not know that. But the errors above make me wonder if OP is using a pre-Java8 compiler.

Comment: @MikeHarris I didn't either! He commented on an answer that he's using Java 7.

Comment: @Josejulio Yep, I missed that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change Checker class like this:

```
 public class Checker {

    public static final Comparator<Player> asc = new Comparator<Player>() {     
        public int compare(Player o1, Player o2) {
             if(o1.score != o2.score)
                 return o1.score - o2.score;
             else
                 return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
        }
    };

    public static final Comparator<Player> desc = new Comparator<Player>() {        
        public int compare(Player o1, Player o2) {
             if(o1.score != o2.score)
                 return o2.score - o1.score;
             else
                 return o2.name.compareTo(o1.name);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use method handle syntax to access properties of an object. Use lambdas instead:

```
 private static final Comparator<Player> asc = Comparator
     .comparingInt((Player p) -> p.score).thenComparing((Player p) -> p.name);
```

Comment: `Solution.java:7: error: ')' expected
     .comparingInt((Player p) -> p.score).thenComparing((Player p) -> p.name);`

Comment: Can't post the full compilation error here, but this one gives error too. Cant seem to understand what's going wrong here.

Comment: @Zeus are you using an old JDK?

Comment: Judging from the errors on his post, he seems to be using a version prior 1.8.

Comment: @Zeus:  `Comparator.comparingInt` was introduced in 1.8. You need to upgrade.

Comment: Well the code is running in a web based environment , I can't upgrade. Is there an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: write a comparator in oldschool style

Comment: How do I write the desc/asc sorter for java 7. Never done that before. I'm new to Java.

Answer (score 0):

For Java 1.7

```
class Compare implements Comparator<Player>{
boolean descending;
@Override
public int compare(Player o1, Player o2) {
         if(o1.score < o2.score)
             return -1;
         else if(o1.score > o2.score)
             return 1;
         else
             return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
    }
}

class Checker{
    Comparator<Player> asc = new Compare();
    Comparator<Player> desc = Collections.reverseOrder(asc);
}
```

And following is your main method:

```
    Player[] players = new Player[3];
    Checker check = new Checker();
    Arrays.sort(players,check.desc);
```

Comment: My question clearly mentions that I cannot change the calling code. I have to implement `check.desc`

Comment: @Zeus yes, I `check.desc` is there in the above code. You van edit the variable name if you want.

Comment: I still can't change the main method.

Comment: Are you saying that `Compare` class is troubling you? You can rename it as Checker if you want

Comment: What I mean is that I can't make any changes in main. So main stays `Arrays.sort(Player,check.desc);`

Comment: Downvoter: Give us some more trouble and provide some explanation for your deeds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106383/discussion-between-zeus-and-pankaj-singhal).

Comment: @Zeus Changed the code acc. to your need. check now.

Comment: @Zeus mine is less error prone. less code. less testing.